# Firestore Query to Sum Values Where DocRef - not working

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

**Resolved**
The parameter to pass should be just the uid, not the reference path (/users/...) and I updated the loop logic to get the accurate result. It's working now.

**Previous comments**

I'm at my wits end with this one. It seems so simple.

The following is in an API call I've built with a string parameter for 'userRef'.

The goal is to sum the total points in a 'rewards' collection where the variable 'userRef' is equal to the stored doc reference in that collection. There don't appear to be any errors, but even when I remove the where clause it results in 0. Any guidance as to what I'm doing wrong is appreciated.

The references in the documents are stored as DocumentReferences and not strings. The pointsValues are integers.

**Updated details**

*Database*
Here's the database structure on Firestore:
[pointsValue is a number and userRef is a DocRef](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qWV6.png)

*Input*
In the example below, I'm just pulling all values for pointsValue without the where statement. Ideally, I'd like to use a parameter where I pass 'userRef' as a string, "9vDyJbZPIBO6mmnG4UvIwGZZW6i2", and then convert it to a document reference. You can see that code is commented out.

*Output and Network Details*
The return variable 'totalPointsValue' should be the sum of 'pointsValue' as an integer.

```
import { Firestore } from '@google-cloud/firestore';

export default async function firestoreQuerySum({
    collection,
    projectId,
    userRef
}) {
    try {
        const db = new Firestore(projectId && projectId.length > 1 ? {
            projectId: projectId.trim()
        } : undefined);

        // Assuming userRef is the user ID passed as a string
        const userDocRef = db.collection('users').doc(userRef);
        
        let query = db.collection(collection).where('userRef', '==', userDocRef);
        let snapshot = await query.get();

        /* let totalPointsValue = 0;
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          totalPointsValue += doc.data().pointsValue || 0;
        }); */

        const totalPointsValue = snapshot.docs.reduce((total, doc) => {
            return total + (doc.data().pointsValue || 0);
        }, 0);

        return totalPointsValue;
    }
    catch(e) {
        return e;
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't see any of the variables you're using for this query, and we can't see the data in your database.  This means we have no idea what will happen when this code runes. Please edit the question to provide enough information and instruction that anyone can use to reproduce the results you observe.

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, so (as Doug commented already) the problem is likely somewhere that we can't see it - like how you are calling/using `firestoreQuerySum`, the data it's trying to load, the network connection, etc. I recommend reading [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) (especially the part about [logging your results](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example#2-state-your-observations)) and updating your question based on that.

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback. I was able to resolve it. I'll leave it posted in case others have this problem.